# Conflict in liquibase

Tags: database, liquibase

It is possible to rollback all queries in liquibase when exception was throwing?
For example:

1. Tom has a task: remove column "column1" in "table1"
2. Donald has a task: change type of "column1" to int

In my changeLog file are:

```
<include file="liquibase/tom-task.xml"/> 
<include file="liquibase/donald-task.xml"/>
```

Script in donald-task.xml throw exception because "column1" doesn't exist. Someone who created tasks made a mistakes so I want to revert my last version of database with "column1"

Answer (score 1):

You need to run Liquibase rollback command (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) and rollback a number of last changesets or to a tag.